# how to create a IB action for a image view

Tags: iphone, image, ibaction

i have a image ,i want to  launch url when i press that logo or image ,how to implement ib action for that image view ...
can any one give suggestion  i selected image view in ib to place my logo  is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImageView` is not a subclass of `UIControl` so it doesn't support the target-action mechanism. You have 2 options:

1. Use a `UIButton` instead (and set your image as the button's background image).
2. Set `userInteractionEnabled = YES;` on your image view and implement the touch handling in -touchesMoved:` etc. yourself.